# xcode 12 top status bar stays translucent even when I choose opaque in the menu (webview)

Tags: ios, xcode, statusbar

The question is about making the top status bars opaque using a webview in fullscreen

I have this code

```
let url = URL(string: "https://www.stubfee.com/account/")!
let jRequest = URLRequest(url: url)
webView.scrollView.showsHorizontalScrollIndicator = false
webView.scrollView.showsVerticalScrollIndicator = false
webView.load(jRequest)
        
navigationController?.isToolbarHidden = true
navigationController?.isNavigationBarHidden = true
```

but the result is this
[image]

I've tried

```
<meta content="viewport-fit=cover" >
```

but it's not what I want, I want the status bar to stay the same, but opaque, just not translucent...

I tried also in main.storyboard

[image]
but still not working

I tried `navigationController?.navigationBar.isTranslucent = false` not working too :(

What else can I try ?

Answer (score 0):

I found a 2 side solution.

SIDE 1 : info.plist
https://sarunw.com/posts/how-to-set-status-bar-style/

```
// Add View controller-based status bar appearance key (UIViewControllerBasedStatusBarAppearance) and set value to No (false).
// Add Status bar style key (UIStatusBarStyle) and set value to Light Content (UIStatusBarStyleLightContent).
```

SIDE 2 : html : I added a div with good height and position fixed and top -

```
<div style="height:169;top:-111;background:black;width:100%;position:fixed;" ></div>
```

thats way when content is scrolled, this div hides it all ;)